# The snippet to review is good, no better answer found

Tags: discussion, specific-question, accepted-answer

There was no better solution to my code snippet: [Highlight input if empty](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/highlight-input-if-empty).

What should I do?  I want to mark this entry as "done". But since there is no answer, I can't accept any.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as correct to close it.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, what exactly would it accomplish by marking it as done?

Secondly, how do you know that somebody won't come across it a year from now and show you a better way?

Comment: If you can mark a code-review as "done", users can search for code-reviews which are not done. It is like the green check mark on stackoverflow. Sure someone can find a better solution in some years, but that's the same problem on stackoverflow. You set the green check mark if your problem was solved.